# Disable auto-search in intellij's console when typing the search keyword

Tags: intellij-idea

When searching for a String in Intellij's console, you have to type the word you are looking for in a special input. But as soon as you begin typing, intellij is beginning to parse the whole console log which can be huge (it can freeze the whole IDE), and it starts to look for the first letter typed.

So if you want to search for "WARN", it begins to look for "W" for no reason. Is there a way to have a manual "start search" in intellij console and to disable the "auto-search" on typing in search box? That way I would just type the whole word and then search for it in the log, as the word is more restrictive the search would not freeze intellij.

Comment: All you can is copy paste it, but it sounds like a feature request, or performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to bypass auto-search, use a text editor (notepad++, scite...) then type in it what you want to look for. Copy it to the clipboard. Paste then in the search box instead of all characters in it (use ctrl+a to select all, then paste).

Intellij will take the paste event as an unique event (not a succession of many keyboard events).